# How to get multi textbox as input parameter of a Method in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm using WPF C# Visual Studio

I have a method in my public class.
I want to get many textboxes in the input of parameter in a method.
That method will remove zero at first of  length textbox like this: 0123 => 123

**here is my method:**

```cs
public static void Remove_Zero_atFirst(TextBox TXB2)
{
    TXB2.Text = TXB2.Text.TrimStart('0').Trim();
}
```

**What I need** is something like this when I want to use that method:

```cs
Remove_Zero_atFirst(textbox1,textbox2,textbox3, . . .);
```

**What have I tried:**

```cs
public static class Texchanger
{
     public static void Del_Multi_SepTexs(IEnumerable<TextBox> TXBS)
     {
         TXBS.Text = TXBS.Text.TrimStart('0').Trim();
     }
}
```

In that what I tried line have error:

```
does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<TextBox>' could be found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly what the [params keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) is for.

```cs
Remove_Zero_atFirst(textbox1,textbox2,textbox3, . . .);

public void Remove_Zero_atFirst(params TextBox[] textboxes)
{
    foreach (TextBox item in textboxes)
    {
        item.Text = item.Text.TrimStart('0').Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either pass in an array, or use varargs by specifying as last parameter

params TextBox[] boxes

And then inside..
foreach(TextBox tb in boxes) {   }

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
       public static class Texchanger
        {
            public static void Del_Multi_SepTexs(IEnumerable<TextBox> TXBS)
            {
                foreach (var item in TXBS)
                {
                    item.Text = item.Text.TrimStart('0').Trim();

                }

            }

        }
```

to call this method use:

```
var myTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>(){txt1,txt2}; Texchanger.Del_Multi_SepratTexs(myTextBoxes);
```

or use like this with multiple parameters:

```
ublic static class Texchanger
    {
        public static void Del_Multi_SepTexs(params TextBox[] TXBS)
        {
            foreach (var item in TXBS)
            {
                item.Text = item.Text.TrimStart('0').Trim();

            }

        }

    }
```

For calling method use following:

```
Texchanger.Del_Multi_SepTexs(txt1,txt2);
```

Comment: I tried but I see this error :      No overload for method 'Del_Multi_SepratTexs' takes 2 arguments

Comment: My try :    Texchanger.Del_Multi_SepratTexs(txt1,txt2);

Comment: This has the added complexity of having to declare an `IEnumerable`, you can overcome it by using the `params` keyword. I have added an answer using it.